# MySql Query for Display From, to And Class

Tags: mysql

I am having values like Range and Class
example,

```
Range    Class
-----    -----
6.0      0.2
8.0      0.2
10.0     0.2
4.0      0.5
2.0      1.0
```

i Wants an output like,

```
Class From  To
0.2   10.0  6.0
0.5   6.0   4.0
1           Upto 2.0
```

Comment: That's great, Would you like Mashed potatoes as side order?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to get same output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(class),min(range),max(range) FROM table1 GROUP BY class
```

Hope it works

Comment: Hi Atul, your query is working fine but it gives only First line as 0.2 10.0 to 6.0 i also want second line as 0.5 6.0 to 4.0

Comment: For me output is like 0.2 6 10 ,0.5 4 4, 1 2 2 three lines, Please check for values in table and query again.

Comment: yes i am also getting three line output but i wants second line like 0.5 6.0 to 4.0

Comment: no Atul, i wants like min values of previous class in From Column